# How to serialize a specific object of a List?

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, windows-forms-designer

Good day, I have a string collection, this strings save the file path to deserialize it in textbox, (my string collection is saved in user settings).
Bue the problem here is that I want to check if the text of any textbox changes to then, save it again (upgrade it), the problem here is that the file paths are random, it should be chosen by the user, so we don't know what is the file path of every text box.

Comment: This sounds like instead of a plain list of strings you should use a dictionary to have a key by which to identify a specific setting-textbox pair ... or always save all items if any changes. What do your user settings look like?

Comment: @Filburt Good idea, save all, but how I suppose to know wich file is in every textbox?

Comment: You'd need to have a fixed mapping between every textbox and its corresponding setting (`textbox1` maps to `setting1` etc.). If you want to be flexible, you'd need a dictionary to handle this.